# configuring sonar to work with mysql

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I am getting the following error constantly stack trace as follows:

```
[sonar:sonar] 15:17:35.181 INFO      o.s.c.p.Database - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://clbblr-6301:3306/sonar

BUILD FAILED
E:\DEV_JBOSS7\build.xml:252: org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start()', instance 'Database[jdbc:mysql://clbblr-6301:3306/sonar], java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:93)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:75)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public final org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start()', instance 'Database[jdbc:mysql://clbblr-6301:3306/sonar], java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
        at org.picocontainer.monitors.NullComponentMonitor.lifecycleInvocationFailed(NullComponentMonitor.java:77)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:115)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:71)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.executeTask(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:73)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.doStart(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:62)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doStart(BootstrapContainer.java:104)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:106)
        at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:130)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultDatabase.java:131)
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:68)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
        ... 52 more

Total time: 8 minutes 57 seconds

E:\DEV_JBOSS7>
```

I have added the mysql jdbc connecter jar to my class path of the project, to the .sonar lib where sonar is executing locally and also the sonar lib on the server where the server is hosted. still getting the same error.

and the following is the properties in the build.xml

```
<!-- Define the Sonar project properties -->
    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://clbblr-6301:9000" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://clbblr-6301:3306/sonar" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="sonar" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="sonar" />
    <property name="sonar.profile" value="Sonar way with Findbugs" />
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:PUMA_JBOSS7_GBS_ADHIR" />
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="Simple Java Project analyzed with the Sonar Ant Task GBS - Adhir" />
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
    <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
```

Any help please.

Comment: When I installed Sonar i December 2012, It doesn't worked with mySQL 5.6 but with 5.5. I don't know your mysql version but if you use 5.6 try 5.5 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting in the configuration file on the sonar server uses the h2 database (local file-system database). So it gives you a conflicting message when we force it to connect to mysql using the runner or an ant task. 
Fixing modifying the appropriate property in the file solved the problem. It downloads the necessary connector jar also automatically so we do not need to place any jars our self.